# Docker: How to mount a drive in Windows?

Tags: docker

I have found a million ways to connect a folder in a container to a folder in Windows, but none seem to work.

***What I'm trying to do:***

- Create an nginx container
- Have the html folder in the container available on my windows host

  - the cont path: ~/usr/share/nginx/html
  - the host path: C:\Users\myname\nginx
- I want to manage the folder in VS Code

***What I've tried***

```
docker container run -d --mount type=bind,source=/nginx,target=~/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80
```

I have tried many variations on this including using an absolute path for the host, switching source and target, etc. But I always get and invalid mount path error.

***How can I connect the html file in the container to an nginx file on the host?***

Comment: try this one please: `docker run -d -p 80:80 -v C:/Users/myname/nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx` without `~` and `--mount`

Comment: also maybe you can check this similar example which is working on my windows: https://github.com/gurkanucar/spring-boot-webrtc-peer2peer/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: @gurkan `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name MN -v C:\Users\myname\nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx` gives me the following error: `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /usr/share/nginx/html.`

Comment: @gurkan 
`docker run -d --name webhost -v "/mnt/attempt3/:/usr/share/nginx/html" -p 80:80 nginx` This worked, but I can't find the `mnt` folder. I would expect it to be in `C:` or `C:\Users\myname\ ` but I'm not seeing it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word,

### ***PowerShell***

You need to use ***PowerShell*** if you want to connect a folder from Windows to a container.

Here's the commands I ran to make this possible:

```
mkdir -p c:\test
echo "<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>" > c:\test\index.html
docker run -d --name webhost -v "c/test:/usr/share/nginx/html" -p 80:80 nginx
```

Then when you go to localhost:80, you will see "Test".

---

**Here's a breakdown of each command:**

1. **mkdir** - Create a new folder called 'test'.

   - -p creates any folders that don't exist yet. Not necessary, but good practice.
2. **echo** - Create `index.html` for the test folder, that just says 'Test'.
3. **docker run**

   - Create a new container based on the nginx image.
   - -d = the terminal can be used after the command is run instead of showing output from the container.
   - The container's name is "webhost".
   - -v connects the c:\test folder to the folder that nginx serves on localhost:80
   - -p 80:80 connects port 80 in the container (Linux) to port 80 of the host computer (Windows).

     - Allows localhost:80 on Windows to access nginx's served file(s).

Bonus - here's what to do if you want to do the same thing with Apache (httpd):

```
docker run -d --name httpdhost -v "c/test:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs" -p 8080:80 httpd:2.4
```

---

This was tested and works for me with a new docker installation as of 6/1/2023.